# Minimum packages required to send email

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, mail

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and have configured logrotation on it.

Now, I need to know which package I need to install so that it is able to email me the logs. Will just installing `postfix` will work or will I have to install `mailutils` or `sendmail`. Thanks.

P.S. As it is a fresh install I don't want to install un necessary packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `ssmtp` to send emails. I am using this package to send me reports of my daily backups.

To install:

`sudo apt-get install ssmtp`

You will need to edit the files `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` and `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` to use your email account.

To test if it works, try to send yourself an email:

`ssmtp <your email address>`

Then type your message, press `enter`, and finally press `ctrl+d`.

For detailed instructions on setting up `ssmtp`, check out this [article](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-ssmtp.html).